# C# Adding a reference to a class in another project without referencing the project

Tags: c#, reference

I have two projects:

- ProjectMain (class library)
- LibraryProject (class library)

ProjectMain is a class library that should only be compiled as a singular library, no referenced libraries. I require a static class reference from LibraryProject BUT I don't want the LibraryProject assembly to be compiled together with the ProjectMain assembly.

I've tried 'link references' in visual studio but this is no solution as the library assembly is always compiled with the main assembly.

There are clear standard solutions to this issue but I am severely limited by the existing implementation requirements. Only one DLL can be compiled **without any of the dependent assemblies being in the execution folder, GAC, private path, reflection** etc.

The exact limitations are as follows:

- Assembly executed in a sandbox from a third party provider, it only supports adding a single assembly with no direct references/reflection etc (it's horrible but my hands are tied)
- We would like to handle the code organisation as best possible which means following standard best practices, unfortunately, due to the above limitation that's proving difficult.

What I would like to know is if there is a way to reference a class within another project without also compiling/using that referenced classes assembly. Possibly a method where the compiler 'embeds' the referenced class at compile time.

Comment: No - an assembly reference is precisely that. You could use ilmerge to merge the assemblies later, but that's not quite the same thing. Or you could add a "link" to the source file you're interested in (rather than the assembly itself). It all sounds very fragile though - if you can possibly address the limitations that are putting you in this situation, so you can work with the regular flow of C# development more, that's likely to work better in the long run.

Comment: If you define `Some.Class.Hierarchy` in Assembly A and again in Assembly B then `Some.Class.Hierarchy` in each assembly is a different class despite having the same name in the same namespace.

Comment: Umm, just disable copy-on build, and there will be no reference dll's in execution folder. I think your approach needs to be rearranged. Your project should not become hell-hole.

Comment: Enigmativity: I'm trying to avoid code duplication.

JonSkeet: I completely agree it's very fragile (it needs a major refactor but that's not possible at the moment). I'll update the limitations in the question.

eocron: that would be lovely if it didn't lead to file not found exceptions :)

Comment: File not found can be avoided if you copy your *actual file* in post-build action in project.

Comment: @DanHall - Use the `@` notification system. You can only notify one person per comment though, so make sure each comment only addresses one person.

Comment: @DanHall - You are explicitly creating code duplication if you end up with the same class definition in two different assemblies.

Comment: @eocron the file can't be placed with the main assembly, it's a programming nightmare but my hands are tied.

Comment: If your sandbox does not allow loading other dlls in AppDomain, load it yourself by embedding it into result dll. You can create project specifically for sandbox. (no need to emebed it every time, just for this scenario). I.e, you will have *MyDll.csporj* and *MyDllSandboxed.csproj*, second one will use something like *Costura.Fody* from nuget to embed dll inside, so your Sanbox can use it. Maintenance in this case will be avoided, because it does not touch MyDll.csproj.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes that's what i'm avoiding, i will not be duplicating the class as that's a maintanance nightmare. I just need reference to the class without adding its entire project.

Comment: @eocron Costura.Fody looks helpful, i'll try it out, thanks.

Comment: @DanHall - The only place a class exists is in the assembly created from a project. The `*.cs` file is just a text file. It's not a class until it is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

If your sandbox does not allow loading other dlls in AppDomain, load it yourself by embedding it. You can use Costura.Fody for this purpose, it is easy to use/install, just reference it from nuget.

Of course, embedding it in every scenario is madness and often comes with completely obscure bugs, which often solvable only by enabling traces in regedit.

So, in your case I would create two projects:

```
MyDll.csproj //it is my original project, with perfect code design and etc. Lovely.

MyDll.Sandbox.csproj //this one is the same as MyDll.csproj, except it is compiled with additional Costura.Fody reference, into single dll (every reference is put inside)
```

This way you just need to maintenance that MyDll and MyDll.Sandbox files are the same.